# Coin Row algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am stuck on this algorithm question and i am getting the concept but i am having a hard time visualizing an implementation of it. Coin-row problem There is a row of n coins whose values are some positive integers c1, c2, . . . , cn, not necessarily distinct. The goal is to pick up the maximum amount of money subject to the constraint that no two coins adjacent in the initial row can be picked up. I have a basic algorithm here.

```
F[0]←0; F[1]←C[1]
for i ← 2 to n do
    F [i] ← max(C[i] + F [i − 2], F [i − 1]) 
return F [n]
```

Can someone start me off in setting up a basic implementation. thanks.

Comment: We'll be glad to help when you have an actual problem with your code, but no one is going to write it for you. In other words: what have you tried?

Comment: you almost have the code there

Answer (score 0):

Based off of your algorithm you want something like this:

```
int coin_row(int[] array, int index, int length)
{
    if (index >= length) //beyond last coin
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int value = array[index];
    if (index >= length - 1) //last coin
    {
        return value;
    }
    else if (index >= length - 2) //second last coin
    {
        return max(value, coin+row(array, index+1);
    }

    return max(value+coin_row(array, index+2), coin_row(array, index+1));
}
```

call with

```
coin_row(array, 0, length of array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int max(int a, int b) {
  if(a > b) return a;
  return b;
}

int coin_row(int[] C, int n) {
  int F[n+1], i;
  F[0] = 0; F[1] = C[1];

  for(i = 2;i<=n;i++) {
    F[i] = max(C[i] + F[i-2], F[i-1]);
  }

  return F[n];
}
```